# Why minimize,restore down are working without implementing any methods for a Frame?

Tags: java, awt

Here in the code if I dont implement the closingWindow method the window willnot close when i press the close button.But I havenot implemented any methods for minimising and restoredown buttons.But still they are working?What is the use of other methods even if i implemented the below method windowActivated I couldnot see any effect?Please someone explain about the two issues i mentioned above?

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyFrame extends Frame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Frame objframe=new Frame("java exam......");
        objframe.setSize(400,350);
        objframe.setVisible(true);
        objframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("working other events......");
            }
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's all about the magic of OOPs. The classes that you are using and extending from already have this functionality. As an aside, avoid using AWT and instead favor Swing (or other GUI libraries that are more modern and powerful). Also, the code you posted was without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Thankfully Tim Zimmermann formatted your code for you, but in the future, you'll want to do this yourself.

Comment: why they have not provided functionality for the close button?could you  give me an example where not implementing the close button is justified?

Comment: Because they want to give the coder the option of deciding just what should be done when that button is pressed. This could be: close the whole program and JVM, close just this window leaving the rest of the program running, close nothing but instead ask the user if they really want to close first, and check if they want to save data before closing,...

Comment: what is the use of other methods.In above code i implemented windowActivated but the output is not showing anything?Another question  generally we need to call a method using the object.But in the above case I havenot called the windowClosing method?

Answer (score 1):

> i implemented windowActivated but the output is not showing anything?

That is because the window is already visible before you add the WindowListener to the frame, so it has already been activated. Try clicking on another window on your desktop and then reselect your Frame and you will see the message.

If you want the message to appear at startup, then move the setVisible() statement to the bottom of your code (after you add the WindowListener).

> But in the above case I havenot called the windowClosing method?

When you write GUI code you write code to handle "events", that is why you wrote the WindowListener. Now when the user clicks on the "Close" button Java will generate the "windowClosing" event for you.

I suggest you read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics of GUI programming. Yes, the tutorial is for Swing but that is what you should be learning instead of AWT. Also Swing is built on top of AWT anyway. Maybe start with the section on `Writing Event Listeners`?